# How can I add a hyperlink with python/flask

Tags: python, smtp

I am using Flask to build a website. I have an html form that will add a subscriber to a database. When I update the website, the subscribers will get an email notification. How can I add to the email a hyperlink to allow them to choose to unsubscribe. (I have a function set up already that I can delete the subscribers, but I want them to have the option of removing themselves.) Any ideas?

here is my email code

```
 subscriber_message = "You have been subscribed. Thank you.\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nIf you wish to be removed from the subscription list" click here.
 server=smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
 server.starttls()
 server.login(my_email, pw)
 server.sendmail(my_email, subscriber_email, subscriber_message)
```

I want the "click here." to be the hyperlink

here is the code I want it to receive when the link is clicked.

```
@auth.route('/delete-subscribers', methods=['POST'])
def delete_subscribers():
    sub = json.loads(request.data)
    subscribersId = sub['subscribersId']
    sub = Subscribers.query.get(subscribersId)
    if sub:
        db.session.delete(sub)
        db.session.commit()

    else:
        flash('Subscriber does not exist in database.', category='error')

    return jsonify({})
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> add to the email a hyperlink

Send actual HTML payload with `<a href="http://unsubscribe-here.com">Unsubscribe</a>` rather than a raw string.

You may use Jinja2 templates to help with that.

Then it's up to the email client to properly render HTML content.

Comment: Thank you, I thought about adding an html href, but wasn't sure because I did not have an actual url yet. I am still in the building phase so just the local host url.